# Equating a two pointers without using & or *?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to understand what this code does (and if it's even allowed):

```
int * A;
int * B;
A = (int *)malloc( size_t somenumber );
B = A;

// bunch of stuff using B, B++, etc.
```

Everything I've read always shows equating things to pointers either using the reference operator (`&`) or the derefernce operator (`*`).

What does this sort of equating do?

And, when I ultimately `free(A)` what happens to `B`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pictures are always good when it comes to pointer confusion:

```
int * A; // create a pointer to an int named "A"
int * B; // create a pointer to an int named "B"
A = (int *)malloc( size_t somenumber ); // Allocate A some memory, now B is an 
                                        // uninitialized pointer; A is initialized,
                                        // but just to uninitialized memory
```

Conceptually:

[image]

```
B = A; // Assign B to the value of A (The uninitialized memory)
```

[image]

```
free(A);
```

[image]

So after all that I think you can see what's happening. B is being assigned the value of A, which is the allocated and uninitialized memory chunk. So now you just have two pointers pointing to the same area.

As to the `free()` question, as you can see when you call `free(A);` you're left with both A and B pointing to the same area, there's just nothing allocated to your program there anymore. This is why when calling `free()` it's good to set your pointer to `NULL`.

Now way back to your initial question. If you wanted to check of two pointers were `==`:

```
int * A; // create a pointer to an int named "A"
int * B; // create a pointer to an int named "B"
A = (int *)malloc( size_t somenumber ); // Allocate A some memory, now B is an 
                                        // uninitialized pointer; A is initialized,
                                        // but just to uninitialized memory

if(B == A){
   // The pointers are pointing to the same thing!
}
if(*B == *A){
   // The values these pointers are pointing to is the same!
}
```

**UPDATE**
So to answer your updated questions, We need to change the definition of `B`.

```
int *A;  // A is a pointer to an int
int **B; // B is a pointer to a pointer to an int
B = &A;  // B is now pointing to A
```

So to illustrate that:

[image]

For `B=*A`:

```
int *A;
int B;
A = malloc(sizeof(int));
*A = 5;
B = *A;
```

This is a deference of `A`. So you're just taking whatever A is pointing to and assigning it to `B`, in this case 5

Comment: I really like this answer (the pictures are very helpful). Could you also illustrate the difference between `B=A`, `B=&A` and `B=*A`?

Comment: @EliLansey - Sure thing, added a couple of updates for you to cover `B=&A` and `B=*A`

Answer (score 8):

This is not equating two pointers, it is a *pointer assignment*. Once

```
B = A;
```

is executed, both pointers point to the same area of memory: accessing `*B` becomes exactly the same as accessing `*A`, `B[i]` becomes equivalent to `A[i]`, and so on.

Note that freeing `A` leaves `B` *dangling*, and vice versa. In other words, after calling

```
free(A);
```

accessing `*B` becomes undefined behavior.

Comment: Freeing `B` leaves `A` dangling? What if `B` was locally defined (e.g. `if(test) then { int*B; B=A; operationsOnB}` ) Does that leave `A` dangling? Would that cause a double-free?

Comment: @EliLansey No, a pointer going out of scope does not free the memory to which it points. Only an explicit call of `free` leaves a pointer allocated with `malloc` dangling.

Comment: ok, thanks. and when i goes out of scope, it doesn't matter if it's left dangling, right? or is it better to set `B=NULL` before leaving?

Comment: @EliLansey Note that when a pointer points to an object in the automatic storage (AKA "stack"), e.g. `{ int *A, *B; {int x;  A=&x; B= A;} ... }` both pointers will be dangling after the first closing bracket.

Comment: @EliLansey When a pointer goes out of scope, it gets silently forgotten, regardless of the value stored in it prior to it going out of scope. Setting the pointer to NULL right before it goes out of scope has no effect, and will likely be optimized out by most optimizing compilers.

Answer (score 2):

This is not "equating", whatever that means, this is simply assignment. The pointer `A`'s value (the address of the memory block you just allocated) is copied into the pointer `B`.

When you `free(A)`, `B` becomes what is known as a "dangling pointer", i.e. a pointer that is no longer valid to use.

Answer (score 2):

You're just assigning one pointer to another. Now `B` will point to whatever `A` was pointing to. If you free `A` it will also free `B` (not sure how to phrase this, since only one `free` happens). As for the `&` you probably mean:

```
int *A;
int B;
A = &B;
```

which means make the pointer `A` point at the integer `B`, or store `B`'s address in `A`.

Answer (score 2):

This simply sets the two pointers to point to the same memory address.

If one of them is later changed to point to another address, this does not affect the other -- although dereferencing and changing the value pointed to would of course be visible from the other pointer as well.

If one of the pointers is freed the other copy would immediately be illegal to dereference (assuming it has kept the same value after the assignment).

A practical reason for writing such code might be that `A` is supposed to remain "fixed" at the start of the allocated memory while `B` will roam inside the allocated range during program execution. You need `A` to free the memory (and perhaps as a baseline), but it's more convenient to work with another "temporary" pointer into that memory for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

In the case above, when you `free(A)`, the memory block pointed to by pointer A (pointer B also points to the same block) will be freed and resource returned to the system. The address stored in A or B will still be there (we call this dangling pointer - a pointer pointing to previous location of some memory block). Usually, we set it to NULL after calling `free()`, at least for modern OS will cause the system to signal SIGSEGV and core dump when we try to incorrectly reference the pointer later. Otherwise, the program might display strange behavior (sometimes crash, sometimes continue, buggy output) when the same address pointed to by the pointer is somehow again allocated to you.